# If using the Fame and Prestige Point mechanics presented in Ultimate Campaign, when are Prestige Points awarded?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Should PCs be earning [Prestige Points](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/reputation-and-fame) even when not earning Fame?  Would this throw the balance out the window?

I'm a bit confused by this statement;

> The GM decides which deeds, goals, or story elements are most important and awards players for completing them accordingly. Each time your Fame increases, you also gain 1 Prestige Point.

It sounds like PCs can earn PP not only from Fame increases but other tasks as well.  Am I correct in my reading of that?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at these three sentences in the paragraph you quoted from: (emphasis mine)

> You earn Prestige Points (PP) **by completing objectives** during the course of play.
>
> Each time your Fame increases, you **also** gain 1 Prestige Point.
>
> Your **current** Prestige Points can never exceed your Fame.

From these three lines, it sounds like Prestige Points have the *potential* to be earned faster than Fame, otherwise there would be no need for the 3rd sentence.

(if you *only* earn 1 point of Prestige when you earn *1 or more* Fame, then there would be no way your Prestige could exceed your Fame)

Comment: To further back this up, look at the table for Fame increases, and note that *In a typical campaign, you should gain approximately 4 to 6 Prestige Points per character level.* It doesn't look like you usually get 4-6 Fame per level. Defeating your enemy and getting his treasure, returning the magical Macguffin to Lord King of Kingscastle, and getting a medal in turn, nets you only 3 Fame, and usually more than half a level worth of XP.